# How to get click event UIbutton on tableView cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have taken `UIbutton` on `TableViewCell`, but when I click on a row, only the row get clicked, but I want to click only the button on that row.

How is this possible?

Comment: I'm unclear what you're trying to do when you click. Are you saying you want to click a `UIButton` within a TableView cell to do something?

Comment: yes , exactly, I have taken Button on TableView cell

Comment: set selection property of cell as None.

Comment: Yes have done that , but after that, it do not allow to click on Button of that cell

Answer (score 2):

In the CellForRowatindexPath define tag for button and also set target to handler the event

```
button.tag=indexPath.row;
button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonHandler:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

*************
func buttonHandler(sender:UIButton!)
{
    if(sender.tag==0){
         println("Button at row 0")
    }
    else if(sender.tag==1){
       println("Button at row 1")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First do one thing

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
 // This will disable the selection highlighting.
```

Then create `IBOutlet` of your button in Cell class (**Don't create the `IBAction`  yet!!!**)

Then in your `CellForRowatindexPath` create the action of button like this

```
  button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

then create the button action Function

```
func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!)
{
    println("Button tapped")
}
```

Check it. Hope it helps!!!!

Answer (score 0):

you set click event for cell Button try this way

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {   
 cell.yourButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
}


func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton!)
{
    println("Button tapped")
}
```