# How to call a method from parent class to it's child class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my main viewcontroller there is a method like as below:

```
-(void)updateCartItem {

}
```

I want to call it into uitableviewcell class under a button action method:

```
- (IBAction)Cart:(id)sender {
  [self updateCartItem];//like this you can call parent method which contain your VC.m file
}
```

please help me thanks in advance...

Comment: how are you adding action to button in yout tableView ? Show more code.

Comment: Your question is unclear

Comment: action is in your UITableViewCell class?

Comment: my .h file is

- (IBAction)Cart:(id)sender;

Comment: your updateCartItem should update a property. Then you should reload the tableView/ a specific row depending on the need, and that property will help tableview determine if cart method should be called or not.  Ideally, you should not call IBActions, IBActions can contain methods which can be called.

Comment: This may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048504/how-to-get-click-event-uibutton-on-tableview-cell/31049009#31049009

Comment: just put this in IBaction [self updateCartItem];

Comment: You can do this using a delegate or you can use a codeBlock as well,

Comment: What you're trying to accomplish isn't a relation of **Parent-Child**. It's something like you might want to be notified when something happens within the context of an object of your controller class. You should be looking upon _delegation_ or _function pointer_.

Comment: @AnupamDas did my answer help you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `Delegate` or a code block to do this, I will post both ways with examples for your clarification

---

## Delegate Approach

***1 - Declare your cell Delegate***

Our example cell will be called CustomTableViewCell

```
@protocol CustomCellDelegate
-(void)executeAction;
@end
```

and add your delegate to your cell declaration, must be weak to avoid retain cycles

```
@property (weak) id<CustomCellDelegate> cellDelegate;
```

***2 - Execute your delegate action in your Cell Action***

```
- (IBAction)Cart:(id)sender {
    [[self cellDelegate] executeAction];
}
```

***3 - Make your UIViewController implement CustomCellDelegate of your CustomCell***

```
@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,CustomCellDelegate>

-(void)executeAction
 {
    [self updateCartItem];
 }
```

***4 - Make your `UIViewController` as `Delegate` of your CustomCell adjusting your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method***

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.cellDelegate = self;
    return cell;
}
```

> **Full Code**

***CustomTableViewCell.h***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol CustomCellDelegate
-(void)executeAction;
@end

@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak) id<CustomCellDelegate> cellDelegate;

@end
```

***CustomTableViewCell.m***

```
#import "CustomTableViewCell.h"

@implementation CustomTableViewCell

- (IBAction)Cart:(id)sender {
    [[self cellDelegate] executeAction];
}

@end
```

***ViewController.m***

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CustomTableViewCell.h"

@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,CustomCellDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [_tableView setDelegate:self];
    [_tableView setDataSource:self];

}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.cellDelegate = self;
    return cell;
}

-(void)updateCartItem {
   //Whatever you need to do here
 }

-(void)executeAction
 {
    [self updateCartItem];
 }

@end
```

---

## Code Block Approach

***1 - Declare your actionBlock in your Customcell***

Our example cell will be called CustomCell

```
 @property void(^actionBlock)(void);
```

***2 - Execute your action block in your Cell Action***

```
- (IBAction)Cart:(id)sender {
    [self actionBlock];
}
```

***3 - Setup your cell block action adjusting your cellForRowAtIndexPath method***

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    __weak ViewController *weakSelf = self;
    cell.actionBlock = ^{
        [weakSelf updateCartItem];
    };
    return cell;
}
```

> **Full Code**

***CustomTableViewCell.h***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property void(^actionBlock)(void);

@end
```

***CustomTableViewCell.m***

```
#import "CustomTableViewCell.h"

@implementation CustomTableViewCell

- (IBAction)Cart:(id)sender {
    [self actionBlock];
}

@end
```

***ViewController.m***

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CustomTableViewCell.h"

@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [_tableView setDelegate:self];
    [_tableView setDataSource:self];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    __weak ViewController *weakSelf = self;
    cell.actionBlock = ^{
        [weakSelf updateCartItem];
    };
    return cell;
}


-(void)updateCartItem {
    //Whatever you need to do here
}

@end
```